# apt and aptitude died after dist-upgrade

Tags: debian, apt

I followed the [Debian Instructions](http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html) for upgrading from Squeeze to Wheezy in Debian. I audited my packages, updated my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file to get Wheezy sources, I ran `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`, and upgraded many packages. Everything was still working.

Now, if I do anything with `apt-get` that involves installing or updating, I get the following error:

`W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/dists/wheezy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Something wicked happened resolving 'ftp.ca.debian.org:http' (-11 - System error)` (the URL may be different, but the error messages are all the same).

Many threads online mention to try to ping those addresses. My ISP here blocks ping, but I can do an `nslookup` to the domain names, and get the right IP address. I can also use `wget` to download webpages by name (i.e. `wget www.google.com` works, and gives me the index.html file). So I know name resolution is NOT an issue.

I checked the dpkg log, but it doesn't seem too helpful:

```
/var/log# tail dpkg.log
2014-04-21 09:55:35 status installed dictionaries-common:all 1.12.11
2014-04-21 09:55:35 trigproc menu:amd64 2.1.46 <none>
2014-04-21 09:55:35 status half-configured menu:amd64 2.1.46
2014-04-21 09:55:35 status installed menu:amd64 2.1.46
2014-04-21 09:55:35 trigproc sgml-base:all 1.26+nmu4 <none>
2014-04-21 09:55:35 status half-configured sgml-base:all 1.26+nmu4
2014-04-21 09:55:35 status installed xml-core:all 0.13+nmu2
2014-04-21 09:55:35 status installed sgml-base:all 1.26+nmu4
2014-04-21 11:23:38 startup packages purge
2014-04-21 11:39:37 startup packages purge
```

(This post is being made about 5 hours later. Apt and Aptitude are not writing here). The files in /var/log/apt haven't been written to since 09:55am today, so nothing is getting written there either. The `/` partition has 83 GB free (I didn't build this server, my predecessor did).

Aptitude loads, but won't download anything. In it, if I hit the <kbd>u</kbd> key to bring up the Update screen, I'm greeted with all the same error messages, in red, and a dialog reading `Downloaded 0 B in 0s (0 B/s). Some files were not downloaded successfully.`.

I have tried restarting, and nothing seems to change. My current services are still running OK on it (i.e. Samba, Apache2). What can I look into to try to figure this out?

Comment: Did you try another mirror ?

Comment: It does it to every mirror or source

Comment: Maybe a conflicting service (as seen here http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=47012). Try disabling anything not mandatory.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent nsswitch from conflicting, add

```
hosts: wins files dns
```

to your `/etc/nsswitch.conf`

As seen [here](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=47012).

Comment: Actually, I removed wins completely, and it started working... Maybe I'll try putting wins at the end (since it's my Samba server)